Mesh is not sticking with Armature

I've watch a lot of tutorials on rigging but so far my efforts seem to be in vain as im struggling with the armature on a file i have downloaded ( pre rigged).
When I manually pose the model this works fine, but when trying to use Rokoko to retarget against a Mixamo animation only a couple of items stick with the armature the majority seem to explode outwards.
I have then tried to rig via Vertex groups, this then loses my ability to pose manually, the objects move with the rotation but move further than the armature.
I have another model that seems to work fine (this is also set as separate objects and not a solid model), i even tried to emulate the same settings etc that the working model has, but i just can’t seem to get it to work with this character.
What am i doing wrong?
here is the file i am using: https://www.3dforprint.com/3dmodel/primaris-poseable-marine-v/7268

The Rokoko armature has probably its bones positioned otherwise, you need to change the bones position in the Graph Editor, maybe share your file so that we can give a try?

Have you applied the Scale to both the armature and all the objects? - In Object mode, select All and then Ctrl-A > Scale.

@JohnEason
i tried applying all transformations on all objects the then forced the model to explode again, the same occured when i apply all on the metarig,
I have unparented the applied and then reparented each mesh to the correct bone, but now when i try to pose the model ( like an arm) this seems to stretch and warp other nearby objects. The arm armour is also not staying with the bone and moving further than what the bone moves
When parenting i select the object and then the specific bone i wish to parent it to and then i have just used Parent = Bone and not used “Bone Relative”

@moonboots i have added a link to where i downloaded the file: not sure how to upload my blender file :)

Please share your blend file, as long as the model is copyright free of course, you can use a platform like workupload for example

If you applied All transformations that would have applied the Location data which might be why the model is exploding and why I just said apply the Scale. As  moonboots says I think we'd need to see the file to be able to see what's going on.
